# Closed form for the sum of 2 raised to the proper divisors of a positive integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation

Is there a known closed form for the sum of 2 raised to the proper divisors of a positive integer?

The problem arises in counting the number of binary sequences that can be "cycles" that repeat at the end of the binary representation of a rational number in the (0,1) interval, after a given "prefix" segment. (Irrational numbers don't have such forever repeating cycles.)

For example, for 12 the proper divisors are 2, 3, 4 and 6, so the answer would be $2^2+2^3+2^4+2^6 = 4+8+16+64=92$. I am actually interested in the case when 1 is included in the proper divisors but that's just 2 larger than the sum without 1. (In case of 12, $2^1$ would need to be added, making the sum 94.)

Numerical experimentation lead to sequences that are not in OEIS (the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) so I don't have much of a start. The first 20 sums are 0,0,0,4,0,12,0,20,8,36,0,92,0,132,40,276,0,588,0,1076. The zeros stand for the prime numbers (and 1 for the first 0). Adding 2 to each number to include 1 as proper divisor (prime numbers would be represented by 2s instead of zeros) is also absent from OEIS.

Any hint for a formula, hopefully with a proof, would be much appreciated.

Comment: "The problem arises in counting the cardinalities of certain finite sets, or equivalently, counting certain binary sequences." -- Perhaps it would be relevant to describe the scenario you're looking at. Maybe there's a different approach that lends itself to a nicer, closed form.

Comment: Edited the question by replacing the vague references to a more specific problem. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is indeed a closed form for this, @Ohcolowisc.  Good luck on your investigations!

Comment: I would add that the divisors come from the fact that if a longer "cycle" consists of nothing else than repetitions of a shorter sub-cycle then the length of the shorter sub-cycle is a proper divisor of the length of the longer (containing) "cycle". Such repetition-based "cycles" should not be counted since they were already counted when counting at the sub-cycle level. Their number is the sum of 2 raised to the proper divisors (including 1).

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris: what makes you think that? My first thought was that this is a fairly natural question that might have occurred to someone before. I might be wrong, though, in which case this is a new problem in summation, elementary number theory, in the theory of finite sets or in combinatorics. My hope, of course, would be that it is known to someone, somewhere :-)

Comment: @Ohcolowisc: I made that statement based on my prior experience with the aliquot sum function.  But who knows?  Like you said, somebody out there might already know the answer to your question.  =)

Comment: [OEIS A055895](https://oeis.org/A055895) is $\sum\limits_{d:d|n} 2^d$ which is related to what you are asking but $2^n+2$ higher.  [OEIS A034729](https://oeis.org/A034729) is half that

Comment: @Henry: Thank you so much, Henry. Your hint definitely answers part of my question. What's missing is that the formulas given in OEIS are not closed forms per se, rather they are sums. But they are certainly a starting point. E.g. by pointing out that A055895 is the Inverse Moebius transform of powers of 2. Your comment is much appreciated.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris: I have to agree with you. As per Henry's hints, the sequence is related to Moebius transforms and their inverses that generally don't seem to have known closed forms.  They have generating functions, equivalent finite sums and equivalent infinite sums but not closed forms. Thank you for pointing out this circumstance.